# Is there an efficient way to do semidefinite programming with a Lyapunov equation constraint?

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, numerical-linear-algebra, semidefinite-programming

I am trying to numerically solve semidefinite programs of the form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X,Y}{\text{minimize}} & \operatorname{tr}(AX)\\ \text{subject to} & BY + YB = X\\ & X, Y \succcurlyeq 0\end{array}$$

The matrices $A$ and $B$ are given from the linearization of the dynamical equations I am using and $X \succcurlyeq 0$ corresponds to $X$ being positive semidefinite.

The issue here is that my systems can get quite large, such that the constraint linear system appears to become a bottleneck using standard numerical solvers (Convex.jl using SCS/COSMO).
I am attributing this to the fact that the constraint Lyapunov equation becomes quite large. I know that there are reasonably efficient algorithms for Lyapunov equations in general (Bartels-Stewart), but was wondering if there was a technique that could be employed in this SDP setting.

Comment: How large? Are you vectorizing the Lyapunov equation? Is $B$ symmetric?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The Lyapunov equation is put into Convex.jl as-is, so I can only assume that it will be vectorized internally (unless Convex is smart enough to do something else). B is SPD as well.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/15926).

Comment: Thank you @RodrigodeAzevedo. It's funny that power flow is exactly my application here.

Comment: Perhaps Computational Science SE or Operations Research SE would be better homes for this question.